# Animate Z-index in a continuous loop with css3

Tags: html, css

I am trying to loop the divs A, B, C, D continuously and in order using the z-index but I am unable to get the timing right.

I have a codepen [here](http://cdpn.io/kupEf)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I am unable to get the timing right"?

Comment: @kleinfreund i assume divs don't show in correct order. Important notice - z-index CANNOT be animate in firefox!

Comment: @LorDex I tested this codepen link, it works just fine in Firefox.

Comment: i mean it doesn't animate like 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10 - only 1-10  please refer to http://css-tricks.com/css-animation-tricks/ - section "Some other things to note"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get the timing right for the `alternate` animation, but here's a working loop that works perfectly, but without alternating:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wtqLA

Changes:

- `animation: move 4s linear infinite;` -> `animation: move 16s linear infinite;`
- `.block-b {animation-delay: 4s;}` -> `.block-b {animation-delay: 8s;}
- `.block-c {animation-delay: 8s;}` -> `.block-b {animation-delay: 12s;}
- `.block-d {animation-delay: 12s;}` -> `.block-b {animation-delay: 16s;}

Also I've added an extra keyframe so that the animation only starts changing z-index at the end of the animation, for better timing:

```
@keyframes move {
  0% { z-index: 0; }
  50% { z-index: 0; }
  100% { z-index: 10; }
}
```

I hope this is good enough for you. I couldn't get it to work properly with alternating directions

Comment: Thanks joeytje50 that worked perfectly and it was exactly what I wanted it to do. I love your mineturtle btw :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 animations are not yet out of the "experimental" phase in some browsers. As you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/css-animation), WebKit browsers (including Opera) still need a prefix to work properly. I am assuming you're testing it in one of the browsers that require the `-webkit-` prefix. It works perfectly when I open that page in Firefox.

I've added the prefixes that make the animation work in all browsers [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wtqLA).

I realise this is not an answer to your question, but it is a very serious problem if you would want to publish it anywhere.

Comment: Cheers I know about the vendor prefixes but I thought it would be easier to read without them, but next time I will have them all when asking a question. ;)